# Fetch previous word in a pattern

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds

I have a scenario to fetch previous word from a string in Perl. For example

```
$str = "there are lot of apples <xref id=1> and " .
       "a lot of oranges <xref id=2> as blah blah";
```

I need to fetch the previous word ('apples' and 'oranges' above) before each `<xref(.*?)>`

Comment: Reverse your thinking: match a word that is followed by an xref tag. Now show us what you have tried, and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my $str = "there are lot of apples <xref id=1> and lot of oranges <xref id=2> as blah blah";

for my $substr ( $str =~ m{(\w+)(?= <xref id)}g ) {
    print "- $substr\n";
}
```

The key is [(?=...)](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.18.0/pod/perlre.pod#Look) part.

But - you actually don't need the assertions. You can, just as Massa suggested, use normal regexp:

```
for my $substr ( $str =~ m{(\w+)\s+<xhref id}g ) {
```

and it will work just as fine (well, aside from some really weird edge cases.